# JOOQ - How to use array_agg with custom type field

Tags: jooq

I am using Jooq (with PostgreSQL). I need to use `array_agg` on some query, for aggregating values from a field which is of a custom type.

```
 SELECT TABLE.FIELD1, array_agg(TABLE.FIELD2) FROM TABLE GROUP BY TABLE.FIELD1;

dslContext.select(TABLE.FIELD1, arrayAgg(TABLE.FIELD2))
            .from(TABLE)
            .groupBy(TABLE.FIELD1)
            .fetch();
```

FIELD2 is a `int8` column in DB which typically maps into Java Long.

I have defined a `TypeConverter`forcing conversion to some Java class.

The conversions works fine in all queries but when using `array_agg` it fails with exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while reading field: array_agg("PUBLIC"."TABLE"."FIELD2"), at JDBC index: 2
        at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1781)
        at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1740)
        at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1705)
        at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:125)
        at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchNext(CursorImpl.java:1669)
        ... 120 more
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from 15 (class java.lang.Long) to class <my custom class>
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1167)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:1056)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:322)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:314)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:386)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convertArray(Convert.java:293)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:537)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:322)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:314)
        at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:386)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultArrayBinding.convertArray(DefaultBinding.java:1128)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultArrayBinding.pgGetArray(DefaultBinding.java:1117)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultArrayBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:1033)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$DefaultArrayBinding.get0(DefaultBinding.java:912)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding$AbstractBinding.get(DefaultBinding.java:775)
        at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1771)
```

Any workaround? Is it a JOOQ limitation?

Thanks!
 Dan

Comment: Could this be related to https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7471? Lukas Eder, the author of jOOQ, mentions there that this feature _should_ work just fine. Maybe try creating a complete, minimal reproduction example and chime in that ticket. Also, which version of jOOQ are you using?

Comment: Thank you @PetrJaneček for the issue reference, it looks like I hit the same issue. I tried it with latest JOOQ version (3.11.11) and the issue is reproducible on that version.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually ended up with the following workaround:

```
dslContext.select(TABLE.FIELD1, arrayAgg(TABLE.FIELD2).coerce(Long[].class))
            .from(TABLE)
            .groupBy(TABLE.FIELD1)
            .fetch();
```

And the converting the Long to my custom type after fetching.